# iPhone app using SMTP

Tags: iphone, ios, smtp

I'm creating an app for iPhone that uses SMTP to automatically send emails to a pre set address. Would this sort of thing be accepted if it was submitted to the app store, or do apple only allow emails to be sent using the UI?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Apple won't reject the app for not using the built-in mail APIs, as long as you're not using in private API in your implementation of the SMTP client.

That said, Apple's concern is messages sent in the name of a user without their explicit consent.  If you are using their personal information (e-mail address) then if they detect this you'll either have to switch to the native API or be required to prompt the user before you send.

You might be better off having the iOS app contact a server and have that server send the email.  Apple has no way of detecting that.

Comment: I agree, there is no documented reason for non-acceptance by Apple. For me, the key issue with connecting to and sending via an SMTP server from an iPhone app is that it's really hard to do it securely. If you need to login, the username and password will be embedded in the app - and if someone discovers it they can send spam out through your server. If you need to change that username and password, you'll either need to release a new version of the app or have some sort of autoupdate mechanism, that someone could also discover and obtain the new credentials. It's fraught with issues.